# htaccess will not work as supposed to for removing directory and removing parts of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I cannot get the profile.php?username= to go away for some reason. I did the exact same thing in another folder and it is working but won't work on this folder and I don't see my mistake.
The other problem, I want files inside my pages directory to be displayed like: localhost/test_a/filename (while the true location is localhost/test_a/pages/filename) but I don't know how to internally redirect to it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# externally redirect /dir/foo to /foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} pages/
RewriteRule pages/(.*)$ test_a/$1 [L,NC,R]

# internally forward /foo to /dir/foo
--------------------------------------------------------------what goes here?

#  externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ test_a/$1.php [L]


# Remove long profile url to simple 'profile/username'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ test_a/profile.php?username=$1
-------------------------------------------------------why is this not working?

#Deny access to htaccess
<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try turning multiviews off. In some installations, multiviews is turned on which tells mod_negotiation to try and "guess" a request filename. In this case, `/profile/asdasds` is being guessed to be `/profile.php/asdasds` and that will bypass your mod_rewrite rule entirely.

So add this to the top:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

As for the first question, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test_a/pages/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/test_a/pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test_a/pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Options -Multiviews didn't help, and the pages/ doesn't remove that from the url and the page goes to 404 error